# How to create discord token joiner?

Tags: discord

I tried to make a token joiner on discord with the requests library but not from any error but the tokens do not enter even if they are valid
Someone can help me thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

On invalid tokens, Discord's API returns a `401 Unauthorized` error. So that should be one sign to spot if a token has expired or is no longer valid due to other circumstances.

You should just be able to use a POST request to the URL `https://discord.com/api/v9/invites/{invite}`. Then the response from this request would be data about the server or a `401 Unauthorized` error.